# Printout particular column in JSON format from CSV file

Tags: php, json, csv

I have an Excel file in CSV format which have two columns.

- The first column contains numeral values from 1 to 26.
- The second column contains alphabets from A to Z

The code I used to show the data in JSON format is shown below.

```
$file="data.csv";
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
$json = json_encode($array);
print_r($json);
```

It prints out data like this:

```
[["1","A"],["2","B"],["3","C"],["4","D"],["5","E"],["6","F"],["7","G"],["8","H"],["9","I"],["10","J"],["11","K"],["12","L"],["13","M"],["14","N"],["15","O"],["16","P"],["17","Q"],["18","R"],["19","S"],["20","T"],["21","U"],["22","V"],["23","W"],["24","X"],["25","Y"],["26","Z"],[null]]
```

But I want the format in which it shows only 1st column value. like

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....
```

and so on

on the other.

Please suggest How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way from your current code, would be to change the `json_encode()` to extract the first column (using `array_column()`)...

```
$json = json_encode(array_column($array,0));
```

Comment: This is giving me the desired result. but is this in correct JSON Format.
I think the JSON format data is enclosed in {},
but I am getting result as follows
```["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26",null]```

Comment: also is there any way from where can I get the Length of this array

Comment: You can probably use `json_encode(array_column($array,0), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`